# Persisting Data To SQL Server via ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I am trying to persist the information in the 'auction' variable, to the table 'Auction', which has not been created yet.  Entity framework is supposed to create it for me I understand. As you see, my program has made it to the point where the form data is contained in the 'auction' variable.  But as you can see the debugger is stopped on 'db.Auction.Add(auction)'.

Why won't the program proceed by letting the db add the data in the 'auction' variable, to the Auction table?

I'd appreciate it. 
Thanks, 
CM 
Thank you for replying so far but the suggestions are not working. I've written in my code as well as shown the error message again which is the same message I had that started this thread. [image]

**The View**

```
@model MvcAuction.Models.Auction
@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateAuctionItem";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

<div id="createAuctionItemSection">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Auctions", FormMethod.Post,
                            new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = 
"registerForm", role = "form" }))

    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>Create An Item For Auction.</h4>

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-
label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "title" })
        </div>
    </div>


    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date" })

        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date" })

        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DeliveryCost, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DeliveryCost, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "deliveryCost" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartBid, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartBid, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "startBid" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BuyNowPrice, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BuyNowPrice, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "buyNowPrice" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BuyNowEnabled, new { @Value = "Show Buy Now Price?", @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BuyNowEnabled, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "buyNowEnabled" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "description" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create Item" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<img src="~/Content/Images/progress.gif" id="progress" style="display:none;" />
<h3>@ViewBag.TheMessage</h3>
</div><!--End createAuctionItemSection-->
```

**The Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcAuction.Models
{
      public class Auction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Cost")]
    public decimal DeliveryCost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
    [Display(Name = "Start Bid")]
    public decimal StartBid { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
    [Display(Name = "Buy Now Price")]
    public decimal BuyNowPrice { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "bool")]
    [Display(Name = "Buy Now Enabled")]
    public Boolean BuyNowEnabled { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    [Display(Name = "View Count")]
    public int ViewCount = 0;

    public decimal? getCurrentTopBid()
    {
        return StartBid;
    }
}
```

}

**The Controller Action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Auction auction )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
            db.Auction.Add(auction);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
   }
```

Comment: That exception means no array or list elements inside `auction` (check if `Models.Auction` contains at least a row data to insert). Also include your view code, model binding and avoid posting code logic as image screenshot.

Comment: Action is already apart of the DbContext class as a DbSet. The code should only be `db.Add(auction);`

Comment: Please see my reply below. Thanks.

Comment: please supply the DbContext derived class  Normally the template will put the _context at the top of the Controller Class, in your case `private readonly AuctionsDataContext _context;` And therefore do not need to declare it in the create method. Also if you have your server connected in the SQL Server Object Explorer and a migrations folder under your projects Data folder, then the tables should be created when you run/debug your project

Comment: Also what is the method getCurrentTopBid() doing in the model class? models should only contain properties and collection pointers of other classes.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you request he show the view code. Can you verify that is proper coding, as I am unsure if there are any issues in that as he must be using different version than my ASP.Net MVC 5 (Core 1.1), as it uses HTML.BeginForm, where as my template uses asp-action.

Comment: Aside from `new { type = "date" }` and `role = "form"` which should be escaped with `@` for html attributes, I assured that the model passed properly but... due to `[Column(TypeName = "date")]` attribute it messed up. Changing to `[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]`, `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` or commenting them may work.

Answer (score 0):

Action is already apart of the DbContext class as a DbSet. Also the view already sends the Model information back you don't need that as an overloaded parameter. Change your create post to

```
public class AuctionsController : Controller
{
    private readonly AuctionsDataContext_context;

    public AuctionsController(AuctionsDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    public ActionResult Create ( Bind[("Id,Title,StartDate,EndDate,DeliveryCost,StartBid,BuyNowPrice,BuyNowEnabled,Description")] Auction auction)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           _context.Add(auction);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       return View();
  }
```

Comment: @ChrisMazzochi that is not an updated reply, that is an answer that is not an answer. Also you claim none of the recommendations do not work but fail to explain what it says.

Comment: @ChrisMazzochi I was just repeating myself where you had made comments. Updated my answer, explain what you are getting back when making the changes I suggested.